# Remove padding on category page on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, categories, padding

On a website I'm editing - minimauk.com

The website owner wants the description on the category pages to have padding on both the left and right so it aligns more in the middle (see image below). I've done this by adding this code into the category description box:

[desktop category description padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQHlB.png)

However, when this is viewed on mobile the text appears as one word per line (see image below).

[mobile category description padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAcf2.png)

Is it possible to remove the padding on mobile for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your padding stays in place as the screen gets more narrow hence the extra space around your element.
Try CSS media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){ 
 .your-selector{ 
 width:100%;
  padding:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you changed the selector .your-selector?

Comment: No, what do I add? This is the page: https://minimauk.com/product-category/alessi/  and I will want to do all future pages

Comment: this code goes in your CSS file .your-selector should match your paragraph <p> element class. I  dontknow what you element class is so I gave ".your-selector" as an example class. here is more info about using media queries in your css/ sass files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries